# Django - When unique constraint fails, do not allow to submit the form until user changes the field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a field in the model with unique constraint.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,default=None, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, unique = True) 
    summary = models.TextField(max_length = 5000, blank = True)
```

I am using this model for below form.

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['user']
        model = models.Profile
```

This is how I am using this form in the HTML page

```
<form method="post" class="text-left subscription-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% bootstrap_form form %}
                            <input type="submit" class='btn btn-default' value="Update Profile">
                        </form>
```

When user enters the username that is already present in the database, I want form to not to submit but instead it should display a message that the username already exits. I think Django automatically used to do this, but now I am getting an error. Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Actually Django won't handle that for you. Because Django Form will validate on back-end side instead of front-end side. To validate that if user existing or not, you could write an API to handle that, and in the front-end, you can use js to call a request to that API to double check.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Django will not handle this automatically because you are putting the username in Profile when it is actually part of the default `user`.

Your choices:

1. Assuming that your `CustomUser` extended `User`, you could just use the default `user` in that instead of having the username in the profile.
2. Add something like this to your `ProfileForm`

```
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if username and Profile.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
            self.add_error('username', 'A user with that username already exists.')
        return username
```

That is how I adapted my code for the original User model to validate it.